# How to prove this to be an Irrational number?

Tags: calculus

$$ \int^1_0 e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x $$

It seems that needs more than 30 word to make a discription of this problem,but actually that all included in the title. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: $\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\pi{\text erf}(1)/2$ and it appears be that no closed form for ${\text erf}(1)$ is known (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355307/non-trivial-values-of-error-function-operatornameerfx). *Maybe* integrating term by term and using the trick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational will work.

Comment: @Nameless，@Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla,thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question into the body --- it shouldn't just be in the title.

Comment: Excuse me,it's the first time I use this web.

Comment: Related on MathOverflow: [Is the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$ known to be irrational?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461028)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: the proof isn't correct, the factors $(2b-1), (2b-3),\cdots$ spoil it. I will try to fix it.
$$ 
I=\int_0^1e^{-x^2}\,dx= 
\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-x^2)^n\over n!}\,dx= 
\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^nx^{2n}\over n!}\,dx = \\ =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1{(-1)^nx^{2n}\over n!}\,dx=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n\over(2n+1)n!}. 
$$
If $I={a\over b}\in\Bbb Q$, consider
$$
X=(2b+1)b!\left(I-\sum_{n=0}^b{(-1)^n\over(2n+1)n!}\right)= \\
= a(2b+1)(b-1)!-\sum_{n=0}^b{(-1)^n(2b+1)b!\over(2n+1)n!}=
\sum_{n=b+1}^\infty{(-1)^n(2b+1)b!\over(2n+1)n!},
$$
and the $|\ |$ of the last series will be $<1$ (is alternating).

Comment: Thank you a lot!But how did you come up with X?

Comment: @user, are you familiar with the standard proof that $e$ is irrational? This is a simple-but-clever variation on that.